# selection of new anchor changes background colour and removes background colour of previously clicked anchor

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I wish to create [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmcNN/1/) effect with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/meh/8t41aycf/) syntax in place.

Basically I wish for the selected navigation button to have a background colour, but for the others to not. As these nav buttons are within one html page and do not link out of the page, this is an issue as I cannot simply apply `class="selected" style="css">` to it.

I have attempted to use js and jquery found on other questions, but these have not worked for me.

```
<div id="header">
    <a class="head">Title</a>
        <a class="test head"><label for="tab1" id="label1" class="label">Tab 1</label></a>
        <a class="test head"><label for="tab2" id="label2" class="label">Tab 2</label></a>
        <a class="test head"><label for="tab3" id="label3" class="label">Tab 3</label></a>
        <a class="test head"><label for="tab4" id="label4" class="label">Tab 4</label></a>
</div>
```

I have attempted to use :active, :selected and all possible pseudo classes, none of which will work. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to have a bit of JS involved to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me *exactly* what you are trying to do but the linked Jquery can be amended to meet your structure.

```js
$('#header a').click(function() {
    $('#header a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
/*relevant code*/
.head:active {
    background-color: blue;
}

a .label {
 width: 100% !important;
 height: 40px !important;
 display: block !important;
}

#header {
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 1 auto;
 flex-wrap: no-wrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 height: 40px;
 margin: 5px auto;
}

.head {
 height: 100%; line-height: 40px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;
 border-right: thin black solid;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head li {
 height: 100%; line-height: 40px;
 flex-grow: 1;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center; text-decoration: none; color: #000000; font-weight: bold;
 border-right: thin black solid;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.head:first-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}


.head:hover {
 color: #00ABFF;
}

.head:first-child {
 flex-grow: 3;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.selected { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <a class="head">Title</a>
  <a class="test head">
    <label for="tab1" id="label1" class="label">Tab 1</label>
  </a>
  <a class="test head">
    <label for="tab2" id="label2" class="label">Tab 2</label>
  </a>
  <a class="test head">
    <label for="tab3" id="label3" class="label">Tab 3</label>
  </a>
  <a class="test head">
    <label for="tab4" id="label4" class="label">Tab 4</label>
  </a>
</div>
```